# I am unable to find my device even after installing the USB Driver

Tags: android, adb

Steps Followed:

1. Installed the USB Driver using the link: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows .
2. After successful installation, I tried to check the device if its getting listed by run the command `adb devices`.
3. I am not finding my device under the list of devices.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have dev mode on your phone this is usually requires you to go to system and clicking the version number 5 times or so, then enable USB debugging once this is done under developer options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable your ADB in your Android

-> First go to Settings->Developer Options

-> Then On or Enable your ADB Mode

Answer (score 0):

Open your notification tab and check if it's showing USB connected or not.
If you click on that notification, it will give you options to chose to connect with USB under which mode.
There you can select 'File Transfer' mode.